# Reading a File from Cache in Android Alarmmanager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, bufferedreader, android-context

I want to save a File to my Cache. I use a BufferedWriter for this.
I get my path by using:

`CacheDir.getPath() + "/" + "Example.txt"`

where CacheDir is `CacheDir = getCacheDir();`

Now I want to Read from this File using a Reader Method inside an Alarmmanager/Broadcastreceiver.

I use: `localLoadUpString = readTextFile(CacheDir.getPath()+"/"+"Example.txt");` 
in my AlarmReceiver I get the File CacheDir by: `CacheDir = context.getCacheDir();`

When i use Log to see if my paths are correct, everything looks quite nice, but my localLoadUpString never gets a String back from my reader Method ( reader Method works fine in the other (normal) activity)

Did I make a mistake by using the wrong context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct" context probably depends on how you registered your BroadcastReceiver.

1. If you declared it in your AndroidManifest.xml, the context passed into onReceive() is the ApplicationContext.
2. If you dynamically registered the BroadcastReceiver at runtime via context.registerReceiver(), the context passed into onReceive() is the same context that was used to call registerReceiver().

In case number 2, you can always call context.getApplicationContext() to retrieve the Application Context.

Since I can't get a feel for what you're trying to do from where, my initial recommendation would be to try context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() in your onReceive() call.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me out. After one more hour i found my main problem was a missing constructor call so i transfered an empty String and could not read any data. But i used your solution to solve another problem. Thank you